# Storing a pointer in class

Tags: c++, class, variables, pointers

I'm learning C++ and having trouble with pointers.
This simple project consists in a invoice that has a pointer to a customer.

**Classes:**

```
class Customer {
    string name;
public:
    Customer(string name) { this->name = name; };
    string getName() { return name; };
    void changeName(string name) { this->name = name; };
};

class Invoice {
    Customer * customer;
public:
    Invoice(Customer *customer) { this->customer = customer; };
    Customer getCustomer() { return *customer; };
};
```

**Main:**

```
Customer *customer1 = new Customer("Name 1");
Invoice invoice1(customer1);

cout << invoice1.getCustomer().getName() << endl; //Return:Name 1;
```

How can I use Customer::changeName(string name) in order to make this work:

```
(...) changeName("Name 2");

cout << invoice1.getCustomer().getName() << endl; //Return:Name 2;
```

I don't know what I should use to change the customer's name. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong in the class Invoice.

**Why change the name through Invoice?**
So I can learn how I can learn how to use the pointer before the project starts getting big.
Later I'm going to have a vector of Invoices and a vector of Customers. Getting the pointer to a Customer from a Invoice or from a vector of Customers should be the same.

Thank you,
Eduardo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Invoice`, return the pointer to the `Customer` itself, rather than a copy of its dereferenced value:

```
Customer* getCustomer() { return customer; };
```

Then you can change the name like so, and the change will affect the actual `Customer` object:

```
invoice1.getCustomer()->changeName("Name2")
```

Answer (score 7):

```
Customer getCustomer() { return *customer; };
```

should be

```
Customer& getCustomer() { return *customer; };
```

because in the first case you copy the customer object and so your changes happen in a temporary object that gets thrown away...

in the second you will return a reference to the object you created.

to change name

```
string newName = "Edu";
invoice1.getCustomer().changeName( newName );
```

Comment: And how should I call the function changeName in Main, in order to modify the content of this pointer?

Comment: +1 for returning references, localizing a possible segfault to the `Invoice` class.

Answer (score 2):

If you want this substantially hardened, i've taken such liberties here. Both Customer and Invoice declarations are significantly updated. Compare them to your existing code. **Don't** just copy this into your code, as it will definitely break a ton of things. Rather, look at it and see if it makes sense to you:

```
class Customer 
{
    string name;

public:
    Customer(const string& name) : name(name) {};

    const string& getName() const { return name; };
    void changeName(const string& name) { this->name = name; };
};

class Invoice 
{
    const Customer& customer;

public:
    Invoice(const Customer& customer) : customer(customer) {};

    const Customer& getCustomer() const { return customer; };
};
```

In general (more often than not, anyway) the **only** times you should need to pass an object by pointer is if there is a chance the object pointer *receiver* should accept NULL as a valid value. Otherwise use references or smart pointers. Arrays of object pointers to support  polymorphic access not withstanding (and even then, smart pointers ftw), this is generally a good rule to follow.

Significant changes made:

- Uses const references unless there is specific need for non-const-access
- Classes have initializer lists to ensure best-construction for member vars, and, in fact are required now for Invoice, since the Customer reference memeber *must* be initialized in an initializer list.

**Main**

```
Customer customer1("Name 1");
Invoice invoice1(customer1);

// note: invoice now only allows you to obtain a const-reference
//  to the customer of the invoice. As such, you can only fire
//  const-members on the returned customer reference.
cout << invoice1.getCustomer().getName() << endl; //Return:Name 1;

// without the const-ness of the getCustomer() member and the reference
//  it returns, you would have been able to do this:
//
//  invoice.getCustomer.changeName("newname");
//
// As it is written now, you can only change a customer name from
//  a non-const customer reference (or pointer), and in doing so, 
//  *all* invoices for that customer will reflect this change.
customer1.changeName("Name 2");

// note: the invoice was not changed, but the customer it references
//  was, and we should see that change now.
cout << invoice1.getCustomer().getName() << endl; //Return:Name 2;
```

I hope this gives you some ideas on how to restrict and harden your object access later on in your project.